# How to increment the name of a list in python

Tags: python, list, naming

I'd like to be able to increment the name of a list so I can create multiple empty lists.

for example, I want.

```
List_1 = [] 
List_2 = []
...
List_x = []
```

I've been working with:

```
for j in range(5):            #set up loop
  list_ = list_ + str(j)     # increment the string list so it reads list_1, list_2, ect
  list_ = list()             # here I want to be able to have multiple empty lists with unique names
  print list_
```

Answer (score 15):

The right way to do this is to have a list of lists.

```
list_of_lists = []
for j in range(5):
   list_of_lists.append( [] )
   print list_of_lists[j]
```

Then, you can access them with:

```
list_of_lists[2] # third empty list
list_of_lists[0] # first empty list
```

---

If you *really* wanted to do this, though you likely shouldn't, you could use `exec`:

```
for j in range(5):
    list_name = 'list_' + str(j)
    exec(list_name + ' = []')
    exec('print ' + list_name)
```

This creates the name in a string under `list_name`, then uses `exec` to execute that dynamic piece of code.

Comment: I answered the same thing but screwed up the example, badly :)  So you get the +1.

Comment: +1, but with emphasis on the "right way to do this is to have a list of lists", and the don't use `exec`/`locals`.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend organgeoctopus' answer, but for the sake of how to do this in Python:

```
# BAD HACK
for i in range(5):
    locals()['list_%d' % i] = []
```

Comment: Better than the `exec` thing I suggested. Although bad practice, I love that python lets you do stuff like this. It has let me cut quite a few corners!

Comment: locals() should never be modified. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: I wasn't aware how dangerous modifying `locals()` is, thank you. I've edited my post but I'll keep it for the sake of showing the availability of `locals()`, as it is very useful for _reading_.

Comment: Use `globals()` which doesn't have a similar warning. It will create things at the module level.

Comment: Modifying `locals()` isn't *dangerous,* it just doesn't work sometimes (due to how CPython optimizes local variable access inside functions). There are ways to force it to work (just include an `exec` anywhere in the function, even in a place where it won't be executed) but these are implementation-dependent, and furthermore slow variable access.